# Get wrong coordinate in plot

Tags: plotting

I am having problem with getting the coordinate of points on the plot below.
The plot is OK but when I press *Ctr + D* and move cursor along the line, the coordinates are total wrong?

Could you help me? Thank you.

```
M[x_, Subscript[D, 2]*_] := ((0.5 + Subscript[D, 2])/Subscript[D, 2])*(1/(1   + ((0.5 + Subscript[D, 2])/Subscript[D, 2]^2)*x)); 
parameters = {41.67/10^6, 125/10^6, 208.33/10^6, 291.67/10^6, 375/10^6,  458.33/10^6, 541.67/10^6}; 
styles = {Directive[Red, Thickness -> 0.002], Directive[Dashed, Blue,   Thickness -> 0.002], Directive[DotDashed, Green, Thickness -> 0.002],   Directive[Dotted, Black, Thickness -> 0.003], 
Directive[Red, Thickness -> 0.002], Directive[Blue, Thickness -> 0.002],   Directive[Yellow, Thickness -> 0.002]}; 
p = Plot[Evaluate[(M[#1, Subscript[D, 2]] & ) /@ parameters], {Subscript[D,   2], 0.04, 0.06}, PlotLabel -> "Voltage Conversion Ratio = \!\(\*FractionBox[\(\ (\\ \)\(0.5 + \*SubscriptBox[\(D\), \
\(2\)]\)\), \(\(\\ \)\*SubscriptBox[\(D\), \(2\)]\)]\)\!\(\*FractionBox[\ (1\), \(1 + \*FractionBox[\(0.5 + \*SubscriptBox[\(D\), \(2\)]\),    SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(D\), \(2\)], \(2\)]] \
\*FractionBox[SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(TEG\)], SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(L\)]]\)]\)   with \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(L\)]\)= \!\(\*FractionBox[\(Vo\), \(Io\)]\)", 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Blue, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], PlotStyle ->   styles, AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(D\), \(2\)]\)", "Gain"}, PlotRange - > All]; 
parameters1 = {50*uA, 150*uA, 250*uA, 350*uA, 450*uA, 550*uA, 650*uA}; 
autoLegend[p, parameters1]*\[AliasDelimiter]
```

Comment: The code as shown is throwing errors. Can you please revise your code?

Comment: May I suggest `m[x_, d_] := ((0.5 + d)/d)*(1/(1 + ((0.5 + d)/d^2)*x));
parameters = {41.67/10^6, 125/10^6, 208.33/10^6, 291.67/10^6, 
   375/10^6, 458.33/10^6, 541.67/10^6};
p = Plot[Evaluate[(m[#1, d] &) /@ parameters], {d, 0.04, 0.06}, 
  PlotRange -> All]`?

Comment: Thank you.
@Louis: The code wrong because there is a space in  PlotRange - > All. I tried to solve this but I can't manage to do in here. Each time I post, the error appears. 

Dr. belisarius: With that the coordinate is correct now. However, could you explain why is it wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but an attempt to get clarification from the OP even though this question is two months old as I write this. I'm probably tilting at a windmill here, but I think the OP deserves a chance to clarify.

I could not get the posted code to evaluate, but I got the following fairly minor modification of the code to work.

```
M[x_] :=
  ((0.5 + Subscript[D, 2])/
     Subscript[D, 2])*(1/(1 + ((0.5 + Subscript[D, 2])/Subscript[D, 2]^2)*x));
parameters =
  {41.67/10^6, 125/10^6, 208.33/10^6, 291.67/10^6, 375/10^6, 
   458.33/10^6, 541.67/10^6};
styles =
  {Directive[Red, Thickness -> 0.002], 
   Directive[Dashed, Blue, Thickness -> 0.002], 
   Directive[DotDashed, Green, Thickness -> 0.002], 
   Directive[Dotted, Black, Thickness -> 0.003], 
   Directive[Red, Thickness -> 0.002], 
   Directive[Blue, Thickness -> 0.002], 
   Directive[Yellow, Thickness -> 0.002]};
Plot[Evaluate[M /@ parameters], {Subscript[D, 2], 0.04, 0.06}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Blue, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
  PlotStyle -> styles,
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[D, 2], "Gain"},
  PlotRange -> All,
  ImagePadding -> All]
```

The trouble with the modification is that it does't reproduce the OP's problem -- it produces the expected coordinate values when put into coordinate display mode.

[image: plot]

So I ask the OP; how do the coordinates you see differ from the ones I am seeing?